# How to copy rows from one sheet to another based on some criteria?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I need to copy rows from one sheet to another sheet in Excel, based on some criteria. 
If at Sheet 1 in some row cell in column H have "X" I want that hole column to be copy on Sheet 2. And I want that for all rows in Sheet 1. I have now about 130 rows in Sheet 1, but will have more in future. 
Can somebody can help me? 
Thanks,
Nenad

Answer (score 0):

The following code filters the data in `column H` by setting `"X"` as the criterion. The filtering result is copied to the `Sheet2`

```
Sub CriteriaCopy()

    With ActiveSheet.Range("A:L")
         .AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="" & X & ""
    End With

    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
    Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

End Sub
```

Comment: Consider adding some reference supporting your answer and explaining a bit with some detail.